# Fetch the Comments of OOTB Approval workflow in SP 2010 - using SPServices or JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, javascript, spservices

I created a SPList in SP 2010 on-prem platform, where 4 OOTB APPROVAL 2010 workflows have been created and running. Now, because of Auditing process, customer wants information of each and every items' workflow details like WF Status, why the item was approved why the item was rejected. using the JSOM API or SPServices lib , is it possible to get these kind of information and display in a html table?

I would like to get the comments  fields of default infopath form, thats rendered in OOTB approval workflow and extract it.

I wrote the below code to get the WFStatus for the listitems.But, how can i extract the approval/rejection `Comments`, as well .

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-
               1.10.2.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" 
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/
        2014.02/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function retrieveWFStatus() {
        $().SPServices({
            operation: "GetListItems",
            async: false,
            webURL: "/",
            listName: "testinglist1",
            CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' />
         <FieldRef Name='ApprovalWF' /></ViewFields>",
            CAMLQuery: "<Query></Query>",
            completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
                    if ($(this).attr("ows_Approval" === 16)) {
                        console.log("It's complete");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
  </script>
<input id="Button1" type="button" onclick="retrieveWFStatus()" 
             value="button" />
```

[image: approvalform_comments]